# Properly Selecting Effective Dates While Self-Joining

Tags: postgresql, date-range, self-join

I am trying to build out an SCD Type-2 employee-manager relationship table. I have the base table set up already:

```
| emp_id | manager_id | is_emp_self_managed | date_effective | date_expired |
|--------|------------|---------------------|----------------|--------------|
| 2      |            | TRUE                | 2004-04-01     | 2013-02-01   |
| 2      | 10         | FALSE               | 2013-02-01     | 2019-04-01   |
| 5      | 2          | FALSE               | 2005-12-01     | 2013-04-11   |
| 10     |            | TRUE                | 2013-02-01     | 2019-04-01   |
```

From this data, I would like to add an additional self-referential column for `is_manager_self_managed`. When I do the self-join, I get this (using daterange for date columns for illustrative purposes):

```
| emp_id | is_emp_self_managed | manager_id | is_manager_self_managed | emp_range                 | man_range               |
|--------|---------------------|------------|-------------------------|---------------------------|-------------------------|
| 2      | TRUE                |            | TRUE                    | [2004-04-01,2013-02-01)   | [2004-04-01,2013-02-01) |
| 2      | FALSE               | 10         | TRUE                    | [2013-02-01,2019-04-01)   | [2013-02-01,2019-04-01) |
| 5      | FALSE               | 2          | TRUE                    | *[2005-12-01,2013-04-11)* | [2004-04-01,2013-02-01) |
| 5      | FALSE               | 2          | FALSE                   | *[2005-12-01,2013-04-11)* | [2013-02-01,2019-04-01) |
| 10     | TRUE                |            | TRUE                    | [2013-02-01,2019-04-01)   | [2013-02-01,2019-04-01) |
```

Self-joining across date ranges results in `emp_id = 5` gaining an extra row due to `manager_id = 2` switching from being self-managed to not, which is expected. However, I now have to resolve the conflicting date ranges that have been returned. Ultimately, `emp_id = 5` would begin and end with their own effective date range, but the changes introduced would need to be incorporated into the new updated date ranges.

Query to produce joined output:

```
with emp_data as (
select * 
from (
values(2,'2004-04-01'::date,'2013-02-01'::date,true,null)
,(2,'2013-02-01'::date,'2019-04-01'::date,false,10)
,(5,'2005-12-01'::date,'2013-04-11'::date,false,2)
,(10,'2013-02-01'::date,'2019-04-01'::date,true,null)
)t(emp_id, date_effective, date_expired, is_emp_self_managed, manager_id)
)

select t1.emp_id
    ,t1.is_emp_self_managed
    ,t1.manager_id
    ,t2.is_emp_self_managed as is_manager_self_managed
    ,daterange(t1.date_effective, t1.date_expired) as emp_range
    ,daterange(t2.date_effective, t2.date_expired) as man_range
from emp_data t1
left join emp_data t2 on coalesce(t1.manager_id, t1.emp_id) = t2.emp_id
    and ((t1.date_effective >= t2.date_effective and t1.date_effective < t2.date_expired)
            or (t2.date_effective >= t1.date_effective and t2.date_effective < t1.date_expired))
order by t1.emp_id, t1.date_effective, t2.date_effective
```

The ideal output would look like this:

```
| emp_id | is_emp_self_managed | manager_id | is_manager_self_managed | date_effective | date_expired |
|--------|---------------------|------------|-------------------------|----------------|--------------|
| 2      | TRUE                |            | TRUE                    | 2004-04-01     | 2013-02-01   |
| 2      | FALSE               | 10         | TRUE                    | 2013-02-01     | 2019-04-01   |
| 5      | FALSE               | 2          | TRUE                    | *2005-12-01*   | *2013-02-01* |
| 5      | FALSE               | 2          | FALSE                   | *2013-02-01*   | *2013-04-11* |
| 10     | TRUE                |            | TRUE                    | 2013-02-01     | 2019-04-01   |
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this might work:

```
with emp_data as (
select * 
from (
values(2,'2004-04-01'::date,'2013-02-01'::date,true,null)
,(2,'2013-02-01'::date,'2019-04-01'::date,false,10)
,(5,'2005-12-01'::date,'2013-04-11'::date,false,2)
,(10,'2013-02-01'::date,'2019-04-01'::date,true,null)
)t(emp_id, date_effective, date_expired, is_emp_self_managed, manager_id)
)
select t1.emp_id
    ,t1.is_emp_self_managed
    ,t1.manager_id
    ,t2.is_emp_self_managed as is_manager_self_managed
--Added case statements 
    ,case
        when t1.date_effective <@ daterange(t2.date_effective, t2.date_expired)
        and not t2.date_effective <@ daterange(t1.date_effective, t1.date_expired)
        then t1.date_effective
        else t2.date_effective
    end as date_effective
    ,case
        when t1.date_expired <@ daterange(t2.date_effective, t2.date_expired)
        and not t2.date_expired <@ daterange(t1.date_effective, t1.date_expired)
        then t1.date_expired
        else t2.date_expired
    end as date_expired
    ,daterange(t1.date_effective, t1.date_expired) as emp_range
    ,daterange(t2.date_effective, t2.date_expired) as man_range
from emp_data t1
left join emp_data t2 on coalesce(t1.manager_id, t1.emp_id) = t2.emp_id
    and ((t1.date_effective >= t2.date_effective and t1.date_effective < t2.date_expired)
            or (t2.date_effective >= t1.date_effective and t2.date_effective < t1.date_expired))
order by t1.emp_id, t1.date_effective, t2.date_effective
```